# to identify wraparound number

Tags: c, algorithm

Let's define a trip through a number to be constructed as follows: Visit the leftmost digit of the number. That digit tells you which digit to visit next: move to the right, wrapping around to the left end of the number if necessary, as many places as the value of the digit. Continue this process until some digit is visited for a second time. If all digits have been visited, the number qualifies as a wrap around number. Otherwise, it does not.

For example, consider the number `32741`. We visit the leftmost digit, which tells us to next visit the digit three places to the right, which is the `4`. Next we visit the `7` (which is four places to the right of the `4`), then the `1`, then the `3` again. The trip has returned to a digit for the second time without having visited all the digits. (The `2` was never visited.) Thus, `32741` is not a wrap around number. On the other hand, `3233` is a wrap around number, as we would first visit the leftmost `3`, then the rightmost `3`, then the middle `3`, then the `2`, and then return to the rightmost `3`. All four digits are visited.

---

> Write a program that accepts as input a positive number and reports
>   whether or not it is a wrap around number.

Input Format:

```
Input consists of a single positive number.
```

Assumption

```
Assume that the input number is less than or equal to 400000000.
```

Output Format:

```
Refer sample output for formatting details.
```

Sample Input 1 :

```
872
```

Sample Output 1:

```
872 is a wraparound number
```

Sample Input 2 :

```
351267813
```

Sample Output 2:

```
351267813 is not a wraparound number.
```

---

**Here is my program..it is showing wrong output for sample input 1 and rigt for sample input 2.**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int a[9],number;
  scanf("%d",&number);
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<9;i++)
  {
    a[i]=-1;
  }
  int temp=0,digit=0,index=0;
  temp=number;
  while(temp!=0)
  {
    digit=(temp%10);
    a[index]=digit;
    index=index+1;
    temp=temp/10;
  }
  int size=0,checksize=-1;
  i=0;
  for(i=0;i<9;i++)
  {
    if(a[i]==-1)
    {
      size=i;
      checksize=0;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(checksize==-1)
    size=9;
  int isAWrapAround=0;
  int x=0,count=size-1,remaining=0,arraysize=size;
  for(i=(arraysize-1);i>=0;i--)
  {
    x=a[count];
    a[count]=-1;
    if(x!=-1)
    {
      if(count-x>=0)
      {
        count=count-x;
      }
      else
      {
        remaining=x-count;
        count=0;
        do
        {
          if(remaining<=arraysize)
          {
            count=arraysize-remaining;
            break;
          }
          else
          {
            count=remaining-arraysize;
            remaining=remaining-arraysize;
          }
        }
        while(count>arraysize-1);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      isAWrapAround=-1;
    }
  }
    if(isAWrapAround==0)
    {
      printf("%i is a wraparound number",number);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("%i is not a wraparound number",number);
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

unable to figure out the error.

Comment: What did you find out when you stepped through the program in your debugger?

Comment: @sneftel it is not validating for the given input value "872" but is working for"351267813"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here.

Comment: @620d Great, it's good that you've identified a particular problem case. And when you *stepped through the program in your debugger*, at what point did the logic fail?

Comment: Functions might make this program easier to read and reason about.

Comment: Is it easier to read the number as a string of digit characters and to process that string (or a copy of that string)?  I can envisage a solution that knows how long the string of digits is to start with, which overwrites a visited digit with a value to indicate is visited, etc.  You need to remember to convert the 'ASCII code' for the digit to a number, but that's trivial.  This allows you to avoid division and remainder operations, which is probably easier.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just wrote a simple code that demonstrates how I would have solved the problem. Take some ideas and improve your. Cheers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//! Max amount of digits in input value
#define maxInputDigits  9

//! Highest input value
static const uint32_t maxInputValue = 400000000;

int main()
{
    uint32_t inputValue;
    uint8_t digitValue[maxInputDigits], tmpDigitValue[maxInputDigits];
    uint8_t nrOfDigits = 0;
    bool digitVisit[maxInputDigits] = {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false};

    uint32_t dividend = 10;
    uint32_t divisor;

    uint8_t cnt;
    uint8_t index;
    uint8_t jumps;


    // Get input from user
    scanf("%d", &inputValue);

    // Input valid?
    if ( inputValue > maxInputValue )
    {
        printf("Input value condition: <= %d", maxInputValue);
    }


    // Separate all digits from input value into its own index
    divisor = inputValue;

    while( divisor != 0 )
    {
        tmpDigitValue[nrOfDigits] = (divisor % dividend)/(dividend / 10);
        divisor /= 10;

        nrOfDigits++;
    }


    // Reverse the order, so that the least digit becomes left most in the array (digitValue[0])
    for ( cnt = 0; cnt < nrOfDigits; cnt++ )
    {
        digitValue[cnt] = tmpDigitValue[(nrOfDigits-1)-cnt];
    }

    printf("Nr of digits: %d\n\n\n", nrOfDigits);


    // Set the start index (left most)
    index = 0;

    // Start the process
    while ( true )
    {
        printf("Current value[index]: %d[%d]\n",digitValue[index], index);
        // Already been checked?
        if ( digitVisit[index] == true )
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            digitVisit[index] = true;
        }

        // Amount of jumps
        jumps = digitValue[index];

        // Jump to next index
        while ( jumps > 0 )
        {
            index = ( index >= (nrOfDigits - 1) ) ? 0 : (index + 1);
            jumps--;
        }

    }


    // Check if any of the digits has not been visited
    for ( cnt = 0; cnt < nrOfDigits; cnt++ )
    {
        if ( digitVisit[cnt] == false )
        {
            printf("\n%d is not a wraparound number\n", inputValue);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    printf("%d is a wraparound number\n", inputValue);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Some feedback on why it's being downvoted would be appreciated. Always good with some feedback :) Thanks

Comment: i dint downvoted ur answer..i tried to give it +1..bt its nt working..well in any case..your program worked for me and for that i m really thankful to you. :)